# Can I disable IE 10 Compatibility Mode for my sales portal?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, ie8-compatibility-mode

Community.

I've looked around but haven't been able to find a straight forward answer.

My company just built this portal for our sales teams, and it's looking great. The problem is that our sales agents all also use a different portal which works only in IE, and they all have IE 10 running in Compatibility Mode as this is required by that other portal. Our css entirely falls apart in those instances.

Now this is not a HUGE deal, they all also have Chrome installed on their machines, but it is a serious nuisance considering that they always have to have IE open and some of them prefer to use IE (for some reason) for all their browsing.

I tried throwing in the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >` But to no avail.

Is there a way I can code in something that will force the tab our portal is open in display in standard mode on IE 10?

UPDATE:
Update, I realize I need to use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`. It looks like that was already in the Head section. But if I open the site in IE 10 in compatibility mode, it still loads all wacky.

Answer (score 0):

```
IE=EmulateIE8
```

You just told IE to *always* run in compatibility mode.

You want `IE=Edge`

Comment: Ah! Darn it all! So literally just write `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">`? Another question then, does this actually change the IE parameter for good or does it just change it for that tab for as long as the site is open? I wouldn't want that, as our users will need to have the mode on by default so that the other portal works.

Comment: @AntanasRekstys: That's a property of the document.